# Can we use Moq for Sitecore Item Axes?

Tags: unit-testing

I have converted to my code from Nsubstitute to Moq.

**Nsubstitute:**

```
var item = Substitute.For<Item>(id, itemData, database); 
item.Axes.Returns(Substitute.For<ItemAxes>(item)); 
return item;
```

**Moq:**

```
var item = new Mock<Item>(id, itemData, database); 
item.Axes.Returns(new Mock<ItemAxes>(item)); 
return item;
```

I am getting an error in the Moq sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, it is possible. Moq has a different API, so I'd suggest to start from [this](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) guide first.

This code sample configures item descendants to return an empty array:

```
var itemMock = new Mock<Item>(id, itemData, database);
var axesMock = new Mock<ItemAxes>(itemMock.Object);
var expectedDescendants = new Item[] { };

itemMock.Setup(i => i.Axes).Returns(axesMock.Object);
axesMock.Setup(a => a.GetDescendants()).Returns(expectedDescendants);

var actualDescendants = itemMock.Object.Axes.GetDescendants();

Assert.Same(expectedDescendants, actualDescendants);
```

Comment: Thanks much for your detailed answer. I fixed my code.